# web services return null to my android app when message is too large

Tags: android, web-services, xmlhttprequest, tcpclient

I want to upload a photo to my asp web service with my android app
I convert photo to string base-64 and then send a message with HTTP get
I do it perfect in my web browser but in my android app return null instead of HTTP 200 OK.
when I send a short message it work good but when message is large....
how can I fix it?
this is my android code:

```
InetAddress serverHost = InetAddress.getByName(My_IP);
        int serverPort = 80;
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket(serverHost, serverPort);

        //prepare and sent message
        //message = "GET /webservice1.asmx/VerifyUser?username=" + username + "&password=" + password + " HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        message += "\r\nHost: 89.163.141.62\r\n";
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        ps.println(message);

        //get answer
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        String f = br.readLine();
        if (f.indexOf("200") >= 0) {
            String line = "";
            String g = "";
            while (!br.readLine().isEmpty()) ;
            while (!(line = br.readLine()).equals("THE END"))
                g += line;
            clientSocket.close();
            return g;
        }
```

Comment: have you checked http response code

Comment: yes,return null in too large message

Comment: can you show me your http connection code

Comment: yes,I edited my code

Comment: I think here "String f = br.readLine();" you need to put a while loop because the result is big so it cant be able to fetch in a single shot, cause of this its breaking and giving null